# Seed One-to-one Relationship ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am building a web application using ASP .NET MVC5 and EF6.

I am trying to seed data to a one-to-one-relationship defined as such:

**Models**

```
public class Client 
{
  public int ClientId { get; set; }  
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
  [ForeignKey("Client")]
  public int AddressId { get; set; }  
  [Required]
  public string StreetName { get; set; }

  public Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Where Address is the dependent end.

Now, I want to seed these two tables using EF and in **/Migrations/Configuration.cs** I added the following code:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MR_TrackTrace.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(MR_TrackTrace.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {

            var clients = new List<Client>
            {
                new Client { Name = "John" },
                new Client { Name = "Mary" },
                new Client { Name = "Philip" }
            };

            clients.ForEach(s => context.Clients.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));

            context.SaveChanges();
            var addresses = new List<Address>
            {
                new Address { StreetName = "something", Client = clients.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "John") },
                new Address { StreetName = "other", Client = clients.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Philip") },
                new Address { StreetName = "another", Client = clients.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Mary") }
            };

            addresses.ForEach(s => context.Addresses.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
 }
```

Now, after adding the migration and updating the database, I checked the tables and the Client is built and seeded according but the Address table has a column named ClientId as expected because it is the Foreign Key.

But this column is not filled with the expected ID, instead it is filled with "0". By using:

```
Client = clients.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "John")
```

I was expecting that the context would automatically set the ClientId for this table.

Can anyone help me guiding me through this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to decorate with [Key] your clientId property ?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi do you mean, add [Key] annotation to ClientId in the Client Model?

Comment: yes public int ClientId { get; set; }  add [Key]

Comment: where you are telling ClientId  is your primary key ?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi just tried your suggestion but unfortunately, no changes.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Nowhere, because according to what I have read about EF, by convention, a property named Id or <type name>Id will be configured as the key of an entity. Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys. But anyway, I did what federicoscamuzzi suggested, declaring [Key] for ClientId and still the results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem by seeding as follows:

```
 protected override void Seed(MR_TrackTrace.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {

            var clients = new List<Client>
            {
                new Client { Name = "John" },
                new Client { Name = "Mary" },
                new Client { Name = "Philip" }
            };

            clients.ForEach(s => context.Clients.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));

            context.SaveChanges();
            var addresses = new List<Address>
            {
                new Address { StreetName = "something", ClientId = context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "John").ClientId },
                new Address { StreetName = "other", ClientId = context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Philip").ClientId },
                new Address { StreetName = "another", ClientId = context.Clients.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Mary").ClientId }
            };

            addresses.ForEach(s => context.Addresses.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Still don't know why EF was not able to link the two tables and automatically fill the ClientId in the Address table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to add the address like this:

```
var clients = new List<Client>
{
    new Client { Name = "John", Address = new Address() { StreetName = "Something" } },
    new Client { Name = "Mary", Address = new Address() { StreetName = "Other" }  },
    new Client { Name = "Philip", Address = new Address() { StreetName = "Another" }  }
};
```

When it save changes, it should create the client and address at the same time and link them together

Comment: Just tried your solution but still the column ClientId in the Address table is filled with "0"s. In this case, where should I do the AddOrUpdate for Address? Is it implicit when doing clients.ForEach(s => context.Clients.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
?

Comment: My only other suggestion is like what they have said above. Change [ForeignKey("Client")] to [Key, ForeignKey("Client")]

Comment: Just realised, with how you're doing it, there should be no "ClientId" column in the Address table as you're wanting it so that AddressId in address table is the same as ClientId in the client table

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly but what I intend is for an Address to be associated with a Client. The Client table can exist without an Address, but an Address has to be associated to a Client. That is why when creating the POCO class, as I've read, the foreign key should be declared on the dependent entity (in this case, Address). And EF automatically creates the ClientId column in the Address table.

Comment: Did you try changing to [Key, ForeignKey("Client")] then create a new migration? If it doesn't work, I'm out of ideas sorry